# When do we include an actor in a use case scenario

Tags: uml, use-case

So here is the relationship. Actor user is going to borrow from Actor Librarian. librarian uses the system to check if it is available and verify user thru a company id card.

I am aware that we don't put Actor user in the use case model since he will never use the system. It is only the librarian who can access it and since we are also not allowed to put relationship actor to actor.

How am I going to represent that this user interacts directly to the librarian and not the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually use cases are used to model things in the *Platform Independent Model (PIM)* aka *Logical Model* aka *Functional Model*.

In this case we describe only the behavior that will actually be automated by the system. That means that the interaction between the user and the librarian is out of scope.

The complete picture is drawn in the *Computation Independent Model (CIM)* aka *Contextual Model* aka *Business Model*

In this model the most popular notation these days is not use cases but BPMN.

So the user should play a role in your CIM, but not in the PIM.

Comment: That's how I was going to answer. 

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mark this as answer but this is what I used on my project. Better late than never. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend notations to your needs to convey your idea. E.g. you can do this:

[image]

Comment: This approach is helpful in very simplistic scenarios.  As [http://stackoverflow.com/users/2018133/geert-bellekens "Geert"] indicated, BPMN is more appropriate for more complex scenarios.

Comment: @JBurnett Of course. But BPMN is quite a bit more startup you need. This is "what you can do either".